# Understanding $P(\max\{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}\} \le y) = P(X_{1} \le y,\ldots,X_{n} \le y)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, order-statistics

I understand the logical statement that: $$\max\{{X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}}\}(\omega) \le y \iff X_{1}(\omega) \le y,\ldots,X_{n}(\omega) \le y$$
But my issue falls with $\max\{\}$ itself. Shouldn't the output from this function be a single random variable?
Why is say $\max\{1,2,3,3\} = 3$, but the $\max\{A, B, C\}(\omega) \ne C(\omega)$? Where A, B, and C are random variables.

I would have assumed that $P(\max\{A, B, C\}(\omega) \le d) = P(C(\omega) \le d)$ Where $C(\omega)$ maps an outcome to the largest value in the real line, as opposed to $$P(\max\{A,B,C\}(\omega) \le d) = P(A(\omega) \le d, B(\omega) \le d, C(\omega) \le d)$$

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Edit: missed some omegas.

Comment: $max\{A, B, C\}(\omega) = C$ does not even make sense. LHS is a real number and RHS is a random variable, a function on the sample space.

Comment: Irrespective of which random variable assumes the largest value, if the maximum of $A, B, C$ is less than $d$, then *all* of them have to be less than $d$.

Comment: As pointed out by @geetha290krm, $\max\{A,B,C\}(\omega)$ should be considered as $\max\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}(x)$, with the notation in analysis.

Comment: As a concrete example, $\max(-x, x, 2x-3)$ cannot be written as any of $-x, x, 2x-3$ unless I first tell you what $x$ is.  This isn't terribly surprising.  In the random variable case, the $\omega$ plays the role of the $x$ here, and we generally don't _know_ $\omega$.

Comment: You can define a random variable $M=\max\{A,B,C\}$ which should be read as $M(\omega)=\max\{A(\omega),B(\omega),C(\omega)\}$. For each $\omega$ you have $M(\omega)$ equal to (at least) one of $A(\omega)$, $B(\omega)$, $C(\omega)$, but it does not have to be the same one for all $\omega$.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you would be right if these were real numbers, like $\{1, 2, 3, 3\}$. You are saying you want to write something like this:

> Suppose $\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_n\} = X_k$. Then $P(\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_n\} \leq y) = P(X_k \leq y)$.

However, the problem is the $X$'s are random, so $k$ is not fixed! Suppose that $n = 3$ for simplicity. On the first experiment, we may get $\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\} = X_2$. On the second experiment, we may get $\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\} = X_1$. On the third experiment, we may again get $\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\} = X_2$. And so on...

This means even defining $\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_n\} = X_k$ would require a probability distribution on $k$, and hence it makes the problem equally as hard or (more likely) even harder (see [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)).

It is easier to apply the equivalence you mentioned to get individual events for each $X_i \leq y$ for $i \leq n$, especially if you know the $X$'s have some nice properties (like independence). For example, this comes up a lot in auction theory for government contracting, where we assume each bidder's valuation function (modeled as a random variable $X_i$) is independent.

Comment: I see the problem. So, it's an equivalence $\equiv$, and not directly the result of the $max{}$ function. Thank you.